# Weight versus gravitational force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, mass, weight

What is the difference between weight and gravitational force?  I am a beginner who want to study physics properly.

Answer (score 4):

Newton law of gravitation is given by:

$$F = G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}=\left(G \frac{m_1}{r^2}\right) m_2$$

The gravitational constant, $G$, the weight of Earth, $m_1$, and the radius are constants, so:

$$G \frac {m_1}{r^2}=(6.6742 \times 10^{-11}) \frac{5.9736 \times 10^{24}}{(6.37101 \times 10^6)^2}=9.822$$

Hence, the equation simplifies to

$$F =(9.822) m_2$$

where 9.822 is the gravitational acceleration, $g$. Therefore you obtain the equation $W = mg$.

Answer (score 1):

See the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/weight) . There is no difference between the two . Weight of a body of mass $M$ is $M.g$ which is equal to gravitational force on the body.